# How to flatten array object at least having one nest in efficiently?

Tags: arrays, ruby

How to flatten array object at least having one nest in efficiently?

I have an array.

```
items = [[["Period", "November 19 - 21, 2016"], ["Title", "Test"]], ["Total", "$350"]]
```

I'd love to change that into array having at least one nest.

```
 [["Period", "November 19 - 21, 2016"], ["Title", "Test"], ["Total", "$350"]]
```

Any idea?

**update**

1. I tried `array#flatten` method but no dice.

   ```
   items.flatten(1)
   #=> [["Period", "November 19 - 21, 2016"], ["Title", "Test"], "Total", "$350"]
   ```
2. ***Also The order/numbers of values within array could be changed.***

   ```
   [["Total", "$350"], [["Period", "November 19 - 21, 2016"], ["Title", "Test"]]]
   ```

Comment: `items.flatten(1)`?

Comment: items.flatten(1) # => `[["Period", "November 19 - 21, 2016"], ["Title", "Test"], "Total", "$350"]`. So this is not what I wanted.

Comment: What should be the output for `items = [[["Period", "November 19 - 21, 2016"], "Title", "Test"], ["Total", "$350"]]` ?

Comment: it should be `[["Period", "November 19 - 21, 2016"], ["Title", "Test"], ["Total", "$350"]]`

Comment: @TSH what are the rules to flatten an array? For example, how would you flatten `[:foo, [:bar, [:baz]]]`?

Answer (score 1):

If the last branches in your tree (nested array) always have exactly two leaves, you could flatten your tree and slice it in pairs :

```
items.flatten.each_slice(2).to_a
# =>  [["Period", "November 19 - 21, 2016"], ["Title", "Test"], ["Total", "$350"]]
```

Comment: Thanks! What about if last branches are not pre-defined?

Comment: Do you have an example?